How to measure difference in performance between virtual function+inheritance and std::function member w/o inheritance?
tl;dr
Is the benchmark I present below a fair way to compare inheritance-based vs std::function-based approach to polymorphism?
Full question
If one needs different objects that implement the same interface in different ways, and also needs to be able to put them under a container and swap one with another at run-time, the most popular solution is to use inheritance:
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
struct Derived1 : Base {
    virtual void f();
};
struct Derived2 : Base {
    virtual void f();
};

Another solution is to have a single class, but swap the virtual method for a std::function:
struct Foo {
    std::function<void()> f{};
};
auto foo1 = Foo{[]{ return /* impl like Derived1 */; }};
auto foo2 = Foo{[]{ return /* impl like Derived2 */; }};

(Some questions about the difference between the two approaches are here, here, and here.)

However, regardless of other pros and cons of either solution, I'm curious to measure the difference in performance with a benchmark.
I understand that the performance will obviously vary based on how std::function is implemented as well as on the compiler and the options passed to it, the operating system, and who knows what else.
But with all these factors being held fixed, I think one can measure the difference in performance, if it exists at all.
I should clarify that my intention is see first-hand that indeed the difference between the two approaches is to be considered negligible unless in very peculiar usecases, as I've understood from the linked questions and other sources. Or to prove that my understanding is wrong and there is indeed an important difference in performance.

My attempt to write a benchmark is here:
A few explanations about various bits of it:

All fs above alter in different ways a global unsigned int,
unsigned int RETURN{};

which I return from main, so to make sure that the body of those functions cannot be optimized away;
I've changed Derived1::f/Derived2::f and foo1/foo2's lambda bodies (with respect to the snippets above) in a way that they alter the aforementioned global unsigned int:
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
struct Derived1 : Base {
    virtual void f() { RETURN += 1; }
};
struct Derived2 : Base {
    virtual void f() { RETURN += 2; }
};

struct Foo {
    std::function<void()> f{};
};
auto const foo1 = Foo{[]{ RETURN += 1; }};
auto const foo2 = Foo{[]{ RETURN += 2; }};


Before the measurement code, I generate random bools that I use to randomly pick between Derived1/foo1 and Derived2/foo2
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
std::bernoulli_distribution randBool{0.5};
constexpr int N = 1000000;

std::array<bool, N> bools;
for (bool& b : bools) {
    b = randBool(gen);
}


I use Boost.Hana to conveniently loop on tuple of 2 compile-time true/false which allow parametrising over the two cases, and Range-v3 to conveniently accumulate the time measurement performed for each call of the virtual function/std::function:
using Time = duration<double, std::milli>;

std::array<Time, 2> times; // 0: std::function-based, 1: inheritance-based

hana::for_each(hana::make_basic_tuple(hana::false_c, hana::true_c), [&](auto hb) {
    constexpr bool B = hb;
    auto const elapsed = ranges::accumulate(bools, Time{}, [](auto acc, auto b){
        /* time measurement */;
    });
    times[!B] = elapsed;
});


The function to pick based on that run-time boolean b is the following, which is also templated on the compile-time boolean B used to pick between the two cases being compared:
template<bool B>
constexpr auto bool2Obj = []{
    if constexpr (B) {
        return [](bool b){
            return b
                ? foo1
                : foo2;
        };
    } else {
        using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
        return [](bool b){
            return b
                ? BasePtr{std::make_unique<Derived1>()}
                : BasePtr{std::make_unique<Derived2>()};
        };
    }
}();


Once the object is picked, its method is called via the following, which is templated on bool B for the same reason as above, i.e. allowing picking each of the two cases being compared:
template<bool B>
constexpr auto call = []{
    if constexpr (B) {
        return [](Foo const& p){ p.f(); };
    } else {
        return [](std::unique_ptr<Base> const& p){ p->f(); };
    }
}();


The /* time measurement */ is the following:
auto obj = bool2Obj<B>(b);
auto const start = high_resolution_clock::now();
call<B>(obj);
auto const end = high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
return acc + Time{end};

where I've kept the random-picking of the object out of the measurement, leaving in the measurement only the call.

The result,

with the few repetions that I can run before the processes are killed for timeout, CompilerExplorer seems to tell me that the two approaches have roughly the same peformance, as the percentage I'm printing, which is (i - f) / i (where i and f are the runtimes of inheritance-based vs function-based approaches), changes often sign; this is the case with both Clang and GCC
however, executing the program on my machine, while GCC seem to behave similarly, Clang (18.1.8) consistently returns positive results like the following, suggesting that the std::function-based approach is faster:
0.0648057
0.0716398
0.0636759
0.0649676
0.0673908
0.0756509
0.0780861
0.0890416
0.090532
0.094767


on a third hand, QuickBench (for which I had to ditch Boost and Range-v3), seems to consistently support that the std::function-based approach is faster, for GCC, Clang + LLVM, Clang + GNU.


relevant video C++ Type Erasure Demystified - Fedor G Pikus - C++Now 2024, in the end the benchmarks show that  the cost of all indirections are nearly the same, "you pay for an indirection", just pick whatever works better for your case, unless you are timing the performance by cycles count in a low power embedded device

@AhmedAEK, yeah, I watched that one, but I want to see first hand, hence I tried to write the benchmark myself, and I've asked here to understand if my benchmark is indeed fair or instead it's just by coincidence that it gives me roughly the same conclusion as Fedor's.

From a quick glance: using type erasure to increase a global integer in a tight loop is a bad plan and doesn't reflect good use of either virtual inheritance or std functions.  So you just spent a lot of time and effort to measure something not interesting.  What more, you are measuring time around a single function call; the overhead of measuring the time threatens to become significant!

Your bool2Obj possibly does a memory allocation for the std::function case because it copies the object.  This should cause significantly different cache behavior.  Among other things, you will just have constructed (a copy of) the virtual dispatch table (internal implementation detail) of the function object prior to timing calling it; std function usuallly contains a pointer to either a vtable or an object with a vtable.  For the virtual function case, you just passed a pointer to a pointer to the object (containing a pointer to the vtable).

Wait, you also allocate an object in the pointer case.  Regardless, the operations aren't all that similar, and allocating them directly adjacent to invoking them in a tight loop is a non-typical use of type erasure.  Basically, I find your test harness strange, because it is a bunch of work to make the use case atypical, which makes the test results less valid.  The costs of this kind of thing are really about instruction cache size, instruction cache misses, cache misses on the object and vtable lookups, and cost of indirect call; your benchmark fails to measure almost all of this.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont, re. using type erasure to increase a global integer in a tight loop is a bad plan and doesn't reflect good use of either virtual inheritance or std functions, ideally I would want the functions to actually perform no work whatsoever, though, because I don't wont to measure the work, but just the cost of doing any "polymorphic work" via std::function vs inheritance.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont, re. all the rest, yeah, I asked the question because I was not sure at all whether my test was fair. It would be nice to see an actual fair benchmark. I don't understand, however, why a in fair benchmark the functions should actually do any work... I mean, the work they do is not what I want to measure (see previous comment too). Please, could you explain why you think it is important to include non-trivial work?

Side note: Make sure that high_resolution_clock on your system is monotonic with is_steady. high_resolution_clock is specced to prefer high resolution over clock stability, so if the highest resolution clock on your system isn't steady...  Really sucks if something changes the time while you're measuring. Often it's better to always use steady_clock and get no surprises.

@Enlico "Fair" in the sense of treating both implementations equally isn't the point nor is it super useful; the point is to reflect actual use as much as possible without causing bias.  A better benchmark would be a full, practical program where you can swap the "type erasure" from virtual functions to std functions and back and test the performance differences.  If the result is "too noisy" to see the difference, that is an answer.  If you insist on a benchmark, a good one won't be trivial: you have to understand what the actual tradeoffs are before you know what to test!

I can tell you what I believe the tradeoffs are - heap vs stack allocation, number of layers of indirection in the function call, possibility that the compiler "devirtualizes" a call (how well can the compiler do it?), what the cost of the cache misses are, how much of the memory access will be "local" to other memory uses, how much instruction cache each uses, how much memory cache each uses...

And then in the end you have measurements for YOUR system, which may not transfer to another system (not all CPU's are created equal not even by the same vendor and not even between generations). In the end it is not about which is "faster" it is about is the solution "fast" enough for your application, if not you probably need a different design (datamodel/algorithms) and the "indirect" calls will likely not end high up in your profiler results (cache misses/failed branch predictions are what I would worry about).
